# transition of x-axis results in overflow

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First of all, no: this question is **not** about the (yet) ugly transition of the lines (I might open another one for that, though..).

I'm displaying data in line charts and the user can select the time horizon. The x-axis then correspondingly transitions so as to fit to the changed time horizon. In attached image, e.g., the time horizon was 1 week and then I switched to 4 weeks. The number of ticks on the x-axis increases from 7 to 28, correspondingly.

Question: **How can I prevent the x-axis animation to display outside the svg container?** As you can see, the additional dates fly in from the left and they are being animated far far outside the container.

Any ideas?

Right now, the transition works probably in the most simple way it could:

```
// format for x-axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d.%m"))
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1) 
    .tickSubdivide(0);

// Update x-axis
svg.select(".x")         
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .call(xAxis);
```

[image: exampleF]

Comment: What if you set CSS rule `overflow: hidden` for that part of page?

Comment: Wow, sometimes it's so easy.. thank you very much, I had not thought of that. Doh. If you post that as answer I'll accept it!

Comment: I mean for part of page which contains your chart.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` works well as long as you don't have other elements in this chart that you actually want to be visible outside of their container. If you run into this problem, then you'll want to look into svg clipping paths.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, meetamit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could work if you set CSS rule

```
overflow:hidden
```

for part of page which contains the chart.